# Inserting PHP variable into HTML link properly

Tags: php, html

My code spits out candidate information and I want a link next to each candidate directing to ?loadcandidate=id

The data displays fine except it doesn't add the id in the link.. it's just blank (shows as ?loadcandidate=):

```
<?php
foreach ($cands as $cand):
?>

<?php htmlout($cand['id']); ?>-
<?php htmlout($cand['firstname']); ?>- 
<?php htmlout($cand['lastname']); ?>-
<?php htmlout($cand['email']); ?><br><br>

<a href="?loadcandidate="<?php echo $cand['id'];?>">load candidate</a> 

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Your PHP syntax is correct. But your HTML syntax is not. Remove the extra `"` before `<?php echo $cand['id'];?>`.

Comment: is `$cand['id']` blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an HTML error. You end the `href=` attribute with `"` and then add the id.

```
<a href="?loadcandidate=<?php echo $cand['id'];?>">load candidate</a>
```